# Bring back the users to the same page after facebook login

Tags: cakephp, facebook-login

I am able to allow users to login using Facebook login API into my website, but every time they login, they go back to the homepage. I want the user to come back to the same page they where in when they login, not to go to the homepage.

Can anyone advise how this is done? I am using PHP SDK3.

Comment: Please share some code what you have done. sothat we can find the problem you can check this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper/5.0.0

Comment: Perhaps you can take some ideas from here https://github.com/akkaweb/AKKA-CakePHP-Facebook-Plugin/blob/sdk5/src/Controller/Component/GraphComponent.php#L204 and https://github.com/akkaweb/AKKA-CakePHP-Facebook-Plugin/blob/sdk5/src/Controller/Component/GraphComponent.php#L204 and https://github.com/akkaweb/AKKA-CakePHP-Facebook-Plugin/blob/sdk5/src/Controller/Component/GraphComponent.php#L411 and https://github.com/akkaweb/AKKA-CakePHP-Facebook-Plugin/blob/sdk5/src/View/Helper/FacebookHelper.php#L65